# running nose tests with a regular python script

Tags: python, testing, config, nose

I have a python script which takes a config file on command line and gives an output.

I am trying to see how I can use nosetests to run all these files.

I read through the nosetests info on google but i could not follow how to run them with the config file.

Any ideas on where I could get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt have to do any of those. Just nosetests by themselves execute any test beginning with "test_....py" and make sure you use "--exe" if they are executable if not you can skip that option. The nosetests help page on wiki really helps.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
import sys
import nose

def test_me():
    assert True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    module_name = sys.modules[__name__].__file__

    config_name = 'nose.cfg'

    result = nose.run(
        argv=[sys.argv[0],
              module_name,
              '--config=' + config_name]
        )
```

You can also pass your config instance, as described in the docs for nose.run() arguments [here](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/core.html).